# Does use statement takes into account current namespace?

Tags: php

Does use statement in php takes into account current namespace?

For example, if

```
<?php
namespace Star;

use Sun;
```

Would it means that, **Sun** is an alias of **Star\Sun**?

Comment: What if you try? PS: yep, I realize I'm expecting too much

Comment: Yep, that is my fault, I should say that I already tried :) And it fails. So I thought that I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it means that, Sun is an alias of Star\Sun?

No. Example:

```
<?php

namespace Trash;

use B;

class A 
{
    function __construct() {
        $b = new B;
    }
}

namespace Trash;

class B {}

var_dump(new \Trash\A);
```

This code generates an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'B' not found in /tmp/a.php on line 10
```